# How to do Django pagination without page reload?

Tags: django, ajax

I am displaying questions with options in template page. on click next and previous I am getting questions with options.

Because of page reload, user selected option is loosing. How to solve this problem? I am new to Ajax.

I posted my script below.

views.py:

```
def render_questions(request):
    questions = Questions.objects.all()
    p = Paginator(questions, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        page = p.page(page)
    except EmptyPage:
        page = p.page(1)

    return render(request, 'report.html', {'ques': page})
```

template.html:

```
<div class="row display-content">
       <div class="col-lg-8">
         <form id="myform" name="myform" action="answer" method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}

        {% for question in ques %}

            <h6>Q &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.qs_no }}.&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="question" value="{{ question.question }}">{{ question.question }}</h6>
            <div class="radio pad">
              <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{question.option_a}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.option_a }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio pad">
                <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{question.option_b}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.option_b }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio pad">
                <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{question.option_c}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.option_c }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio pad">
                <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{question.option_d}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.option_d }}</label>
           </div>



        {% endfor %}

        <ul class="pagination">
          {% if ques.has_previous %}
                 <li><a href="?page={{ques.previous_page_number}}" class="button">Previous</a></li>
          {% else %}
                <li class="disabled button">Previous</li>
          {% endif %}

          {% if ques.has_next %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ques.next_page_number}}" class="button">Next</a></li>
          {% else %}
                <li class="disabled button">Next</li>

          {% endif %}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitTest()" class="button">
         </ul>
       </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.pagination a").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: $(this).attr('href'),
      success: function(html){
        $("#display-content").html(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: hi, you can set a listener for page scroll, so if scroll reached an specified value, an ajax function will call for nex_page if there is any, and append the response to the element which contains the paginated data.

Comment: @gopi please refer to this doc it might help you --> https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html

Answer (score 0):

scroll listener:

```
var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
var ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
// Do something with the scroll position
// call Ajax
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {
     window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  
        doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
        ticking = false;
      });

  ticking = true;
  }
});
```